# Чередование фонем

Tags: фонетика, чередования

Задание: подберите к приведённым словам родственные с чередованием фонем, например РАМА-ОБРАМЛЯТЬ.

Мои ответы: перья-оперение,сердце-сердечный,книга-книжный,искать-выискивать,век-?,гонщик-гонять,пособие-?,твёрдый-затвердеть,пахать-пашу,нагой-нагота,звезда-звездный,работать-отработать,стоять-отстаивать,развлекать-развлечение,копить-копилка,стригу-остричь,слог-?,ребёнок-ребячий.
Верно ли это?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Слова, в которых есть корневые чередования:

1. Серд**ц**е — серде**ч**ный (ц//ч).
2. Кни**г**а — кни**ж**ка (г//ж).
3. И**ск**ать — и**щ**ет (ск//щ).
4. Ве**к** — ве**ч**ный (к//ч).
5. Г**о**нщик — **гн**ать (о // нуль звука).
6. Посо**б**ие — посо**бл**ять (б//бл').
7. Твер**д**ый — твер**ж**е (д//ж).
8. Па**х**ать — па**ш**у (х//ш).
9. На**г**ой — обна**ж**енный (г//ж).
10. Зв**езд**а — зв**[озн]**ый (е//о; зд // нуль звука).
11. Рабо**т**ать — рабо**ч**ий (т//ч; может рассматриваться как некорневое).
12. Ст**о**ять — ст**а**вя (а//о).
13. Развле**к**ать — вле**ч**ь (к//ч).
14. Ко**п**ить — ко**пл**ю (п//пл').
15. Стри**г**у — стри**ч**ь — стри**ж**ка (г//ж, г//ч).
16. Сло**г** — сло**ж**ить (г//ж).
17. Ребено**к** — ребя**ч**ий — ребя**т**а (к//ч, т//ч).
18. П**е**рья — п**[о]**рышко (е//о).

Чередование в примере — м//мл': ра**м**а — обра**мл**ение.